# How to create an AutoOpen macro in a Word 365 document

Tags: automation, ms-word

How do I create a macro that will run automatically each time a Word 365 document is opened? A Bing search does not seem to throw up any up-to-date answers. The Help within Word does not even recognise the word AutoOpen!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The format of an AutoOpen routine looks like this:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
    MsgBox "This document is copyrighted."
End Sub
```

For more information on AutoOpen and other Auto macros see this Microsoft article.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/auto-macros

If what you want to do only effects a single document when it is opened, you can also use the following.

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    MsgBox "This document is copyrighted:"
End Sub
```

For more information on the Document.Open event see this Microsoft article. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.open

Comment: Thanks! (I've just tried searching Word help for "auto macros" and "auto" and can still see no help on this!)

Comment: Must have been a very limited search! A simple search for 'Word VBA automatic'returns amongst the first hits: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/customizing-word/auto-macros and https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-automatically-execute-a-word-macro-when-you-create-open-or-close-a-document/